# Show a popup on home page once a day

Tags: cookies

I need a mechanismo to send a pop-up window to my visitor in my home page. But only once a day. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

[Pop-Up Announcement](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_announcement)

> The module provides a pop-up announcements in the overlay which will
>   appear for the site visitor on the first, second and fifth visit to
>   the site (customizable).
>
> You may create so much announcements, as You need and define where and
>   when each from them will be appear.
>
> Very useful solution for interaction and communication with site
>   visitors. You may post announcement about conferences, great news,
>   "Tip of day" system, information about coming site maintenance, new
>   goods, sales and much more.